# How to make content under a tab bar scrollable without a fixed height?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I've been trying for hours now but can't seem to get it. Please can someone adjust the code for me so my tab bar view can be scrollable without having the pixels overflow? here is my code. will really appreciate it. I really don't know how to make the data scrollable without giving the tab view a fixed height. if i give the tab view a fixed height, then i wont be able to scroll like it like is a normal page.
i want all my contents (multiple containers) to be scrollable vertically just like a normal page.

thanks for your help

```
class BirthsPerDayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BirthsPerDayPage({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BirthsPerDayPage> createState() => _BirthsPerDayPageState();
}

class _BirthsPerDayPageState extends State<BirthsPerDayPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {



  static final List <BirthsPerDay> birthsperdayData = [
  BirthsPerDay('1960', 6034, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1965', 6660, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1970', 7672, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1975', 8852, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1980', 9971, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1985', 11002, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1990', 12176, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('1995', 13648, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('2000', 15366, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('2005', 17085, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('2010', 18852, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('2015', 20211, Colors.green),
  BirthsPerDay('2020', 21689, Colors.green)
];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);


    List<charts.Series<BirthsPerDay, String>> series = [
      charts.Series(
    data: birthsperdayData,
    id: 'Births Per Day',
    domainFn: (BirthsPerDay pops, _) => pops.year,
    measureFn: (BirthsPerDay pops, _) => pops.births,
    colorFn: (BirthsPerDay pops, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(pops.barColor)
    )
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        appbarcolor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.0),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/edostate.png',
                          height: 70,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Center(
                        child: Text('births per day',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                                height: 1.2,
                                letterSpacing: -1,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Container(
                        child: TabBar(
                          controller: _tabController,
                          isScrollable: true,
                          labelColor: Colors.black,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            letterSpacing: -1,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                          indicatorColor: Color(0xFF469C33),
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(text: 'current data'),
                            Tab(text: 'projected data'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        height: 400,
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            children: [
                              SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    BarChartBox(
                                      barchart: charts.BarChart(
                                        series, vertical: false,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                                    DataTableBox(
                                      children: [
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '2020',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '21,689',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '2015',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '20,211',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '2010',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '18,852',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '2005',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '17,085',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '2000',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '15,366',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1995',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '13,648',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1990',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '12,176',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1985',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '11,002',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1980',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '9,971',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1975',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '8,852',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1970',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '7,672',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1965',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '6,660',
                                        ),
                                        DemographicsCard(
                                          year: '1960',
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                              color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                          figure: '6,034',
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      child: BigText(
                                        text: 'projected births per day data',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2050',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '29,921',
                                    ),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2045',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '28,906',
                                    ),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2040',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '27,851',
                                    ),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2035',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '26,530',
                                    ),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2030',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '24,989',
                                    ),
                                    DemographicsCard(
                                      year: '2025',
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                          color: Color(0xFF469C33)),
                                      figure: '23,328',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BirthsPerDay {
  final String year;
  final int births;
  final Color barColor;

  BirthsPerDay(this.year, this.births, this.barColor);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a SingleChildScrollView as the main body of your Scaffold. Like this:

```
...
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        appbarcolor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.0),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( // This widget will make your screen scrollable
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
// Rest of your code
```